# Printing Html file ERROR with Winspool API

Tags: c++, printing

I have a simple application written in C++ for print the Html's documments. This program is based on RawPrinter c++ example by MSDN.

When i use the LEXMARK printer with PostScript driver, i have sucess but when i use the HP LaserJet P3015, it's not works and my document is printed with the html tags.

I tried some settings for HP printer but i don't have success.

I'm using the datatype "RAW".

Why the Lexmark printer works and the HP printer not works?

My S.O is a windows 7x 64.

```
int main()
{
  HANDLE hPrinter;
  BOOL lOpen = OpenPrinter((LPSTR)printerName,&hPrinter,NULL);
  if( !lOpen )
  {
    printLastSOError(os_errorMsg);
    return -3;
  };

  // prepare printer to send data (RAW)
  DOC_INFO_1 DocInfo;
  DocInfo.pDocName = "teste printer"; 
  DocInfo.pOutputFile = NULL;
  DocInfo.pDatatype = "RAW";

  // Start Job Printer
  DWORD dwJob = StartDocPrinter( hPrinter, 1, (LPBYTE)&DocInfo );
  if( dwJob == 0 )
  {
    printLastSOError( os_errorMsg );
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    return -4;
  };    

  // Execute JOB
  char buff[bufferSize];
  DWORD nReaded;
  while( ReadFile(hFile,buff,bufferSize,&nReaded,0) )
  {
    if( nReaded ==0 )
      break;

    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    if( !WritePrinter( hPrinter, buff, nReaded, &dwBytesWritten ) )
    {
      printLastSOError(os_errorMsg);
      break;
    };    
  };

  EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
  ClosePrinter(hPrinter);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Best Regards.

Paulo

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), also read on [what and how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please, also understand that general questions about computer hardware and software may be off-topic here.

Comment: And if it is on-topic (if it's a programming problem, and not a printer configuration issue) then it needs a clear problem statement with minimal code example (as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), otherwise it's still off-topic.

Comment: Ok! I'm not sure if it's a programming problem or printer configuration.